# What is the best way to defer code execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, yield, deferred-execution

I have many methods calling each other that each have to certain tasks, some of them asynchronous, that all operate on a DOM (so only one thread must access the DOM at any time).

For example:

```
object A() {
    /*...A() code 1...*/
    var res = B();
    /*...A() code 2 that uses res...*/
}

object B() {
    /*...B code 1...*/
    var res1 = C();
    /*...B code 2 that uses res1...*/
    var res2 = C();
    /*...B code 3 that uses res2...*/
}

object C() {
    /*...C code 1...*/
    if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.3) { // unpredictable condition
        startAsyncStuff();
        /*...C code 2 that uses async result above...*/
    }
    if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.7) { // unpredictable condition
        startOtherAsyncStuff();
        /*...C code 3 that might use any/both async results above...*/
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have a method that wants to execute method A() 1000 times as fast as possible (the async methods **can run in separate threads**, however all other code must only access the DOM one at a time), so Ideally when the async calls are reached code execution for A(), B() and C() are paused, so A() can be called again.

There are 2 ways I can think of to do this. One is with yield, by changing all the methods to iterators I can pause and resume execution:

```
struct DeferResult {
    public object Result;
    public bool Deferred;
}

IEnumerator<DeferResult> A() {
    /*...A() code 1...*/
    var dres = B();
    if (dres.Deferred) yield dres;
    /*...A() code 2...*/
}

IEnumerator<DeferResult> B() {
    /*...B code 1...*/
    var dres1 = C();
    if (dres1.Deferred) yield dres1;
    /*...B code 2...*/
    var dres2 = C();
    if (dres2.Deferred) yield dres2;
    /*...B code 3...*/
}

IEnumerator<DeferResult> C() {
    /*...C code 1...*/
    if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.3) { // unpredictable condition
        startAsyncStuff();
        yield return new DeferResult { Deferred = true; }
        /*...C code 2 that uses async result above...*/
    }
    if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.7) { // unpredictable condition
        startOtherAsyncStuff();
        yield return new DeferResult { Deferred = true; }
        /*...C code 3 that might use any/both async results above...*/
    }
    yield return new DeferResult { Result = someResult(); }
}

void Main() {
    var deferredMethods = new List<IEnumerator<DeferResult>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var en = A().GetEnumerator();
        if (en.MoveNext())
            if (en.Current.Deferred)
                deferredMethods.Add(en);
    }
    // then use events from the async methods so when any is done continue
    //     running it's enumerator to execute the code until the next async
    //     operation, or until finished
    // once all 1000 iterations are complete call an AllDone() method.
}
```

- This method has quite some overhead from the iterators, and is a bit more code intensive, however it all runs on one thread so I don't need to synchronize the DOM access.
- Another way would be to use threads (1000 simultaneous threads are a bad idea, so i'd implement some kind of thread pooling), but this requires synchronizing DOM access which is costly.

Are there any other methods I can use to defer code execution under these conditions? What would be the recommended way to do this?

Comment: I think a lock would do it. And for the task polling use the build in Task Parallel Library in if you use .Net 4.0 or otherwise ThreadPoll.

Comment: I agree, but you may want to consider a design change.  Why would you want this multithreaded anyway?  You will serialize access to the DOM so only one thread will access it at a time and you loose the benefits of threadding.

Answer (score 1):

As Karl has suggested, does this need to be multi-threaded? I may go for multi-threaded situation if

1. DOM access are random but not frequent
2. All other code in A, B, C is substantial in terms of time (as compared to DOM Access code)
3. All other code in A, B, C can be executed in thread-safe way w/o doing any locking etc i.e. if they depend on some shared state then you have synchronize access to that as well as.

Now in such case, I would consider using a thread pool to launch A multiple times with synchronizing access to DOM. Cost of DOM synchronization can be reduced using thread-safe caching - of course that depends upon a kind of DOM access.